# PHP foreach get part of URL and match to link

Tags: php, url, joomla, foreach

I have a Joomla website and I am trying to check part of the URL against a link in a foreach statement.

When viewed in a web browser the only thing that changes is the part of the URL which refers to layout. Here are some examples:

- http://www.myweb.com/index.php?option=com_jsjobs&c=jsjobs&view=employer&layout=controlpanel&Itemid=111
- http://www.myweb.com/index.php?option=com_jsjobs&c=jsjobs&view=employer&layout=formjob_visitor&Itemid=111
- http://www.myweb.com/index.php?option=com_jsjobs&c=jsjobs&view=employer&layout=myjobs&Itemid=111

In Joomla 3 you can get the layout by using the following php string:

```
<?php
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$layout = $app->input->getCmd('layout', '');
?>
```

In my php file I have the following foreach loop:

```
<?php foreach($this->employerlinks as $lnk) { ?>
<li><a href="<?php echo $lnk[0]; ?>"><?php echo $lnk[1]; ?></a></li>
<?php } ?>
```

Basically, I want to add a class of 'active' to the list item if the 'layout' of `<?php echo $lnk[0]; ?>` is the same as the 'layout' part of the page URL.

I have tried using:

```
<?php foreach($this->employerlinks as $lnk) { ?>
<li class="<?php if ($layout == 'controlpanel'){echo ' active';}; ?>"><a href="<?php echo $lnk[0]; ?>"><?php echo $lnk[1]; ?></a></li>
<?php } ?>
```

Which kind of works but obviously it adds the class of 'active' to all of the list items if the layout of the page is 'controlpanel' but this isn't really what I want. I hope this question makes sense.

Thank you

Comment: Iirc Joomla can do that out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will search for the string 'controlpanel' in each instance of $lnk[0]:

```
<?php foreach($this->employerlinks as $lnk) { ?>
<li class="<?php if (strpos($lnk[0],'controlpanel')){echo ' active';}; ?>"><a href="<?php echo $lnk[0]; ?>"><?php echo $lnk[1]; ?></a></li>
<?php } ?>
```

Obviously if you don't want to have 'controlpanel' be hardcoded, replace it with `$_GET['layout']` or your defined `$layout`.